# why does my link to logout not work in my Django app?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

So I'm trying to do a logout link in my Django app. I've set a view that logs out the user and then redirects him to a template paginaPrincinal.html that has two buttons for login and register.

The problem is that for some reason the link href that I'm creating in my index.html doesn't appear.

my views.py

```
def login_view(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST) 
      if form.is_valid():
         user = form.get_user()
         login(request, user) 
         return redirect('index')
   else:
      form = AuthenticationForm()
   return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})

def logout_view(request):
   logout(request)
   return redirect('paginaPrincipal')
```

my urls.py

```
 path('principal/', views.intro, name='pagina_principal'),
 path('registro/', views.registro_usuario, name='registro_usuario'),
 path('login/', views.login_view, name="login"),
 path('logout/', views.logout_view, name="logout"),
 path('',views.index, name ='index'),
```

index.html

```html
   {% block contenido %}
   <div>
    <ul>
     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <li>Hola, {{user.username}}</li>
     <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}"></a></li>
     {% endif %}
    </ul>
   </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

The error that appears if I inspect the code and try to go to the Href is this:

NoReverseMatch at /myapp2/logout/
Reverse for 'paginaPrincipal' not found. 'paginaPrincipal' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you pass into `redirect` should be a url route name. The problem is that `'paginaPrincipal' != 'pagina_principal'`

```
def logout_view(request):
   logout(request)
   return redirect('pagina_principal')
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to `"paginaPrincipal"`, but you have defined `"pagina_principal"`. You have to change your view function

```
def logout_view(request):
   logout(request)
   return redirect('pagina_principal')
```

Answer (score 0):

NoReverseMatch   Means you have to set app_name in the urls.py like

```
app_name= "app_name"
```

and in the templates

```
<a href="{% url 'app_name:logout' %}"></a>
```

it should work